# Temporary queue made in Celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery with RabbitMQ. Lately, I have noticed that a large number of temporary queues are getting made.

So, I experimented and found that when a task fails (that is a tasks raises an Exception), then a temporary queue with a random name (like c76861943b0a4f3aaa6a99a6db06952c) is formed and the queue remains.

Some properties of the temporary queue as found in rabbitmqadmin are as follows -

auto_delete : True
consumers : 0
durable : False
messages : 1
messages_ready : 1

And one such temporary queue is made everytime a task fails (that is, raises an Exception). How to avoid this situation? Because in my production environment a large number of such queues get formed.

Comment: That is an interesting observation! I, too, would like to know.

Comment: Hi Elver. I was able to solve the problem. Please have a look at the answer (one by me as well). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, Philip is right there. The following is a description of how I solved it. It is a configuration in celeryconfig.py.

I am still using CELERY_BACKEND = "amqp" as Philip had said. But in addition to that, I am now using CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True. This configuration will ensure that the extra queues are not formed for every task.

I was already using this configuration but still when a task fails, the extra queue was formed. Then I noticed that I was using another configuration which needed to be removed which was CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED = True. What this did that it did not store the results for all tasks but did only for errors (tasks which failed) and hence one extra queue for a task which failed.

Comment: Wow! This solved it for me. I didn't even realize this was an issue since I was setting ignore_result=True in each task descriptor. But I added CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True and CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED = False and viola - no more extra queues hanging around after processing! I still might look into redis as an alternative backend, but it is really nice to have found this solution. Thank you!

Comment: @jeffp - Glad to hear that. I have also used Redis lately with Celery - I don't think it is a problem with that. Celery itself forms and maintains the queue. So this configuration is important.

Comment: I actually discovered another thing in the past day that I think will be very helpful for anyone reading this: It is necessary to have more than one worker and to route different tasks to each worker. It is advisable to learn about celeryd-multi and use it. The documentation does not make this obvious, but it is the key to effectively using available system resources and not letting the queue get backed up.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you're using the amqp as the results backend. From the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rabbitmq-result-backend) here are the pitfalls of using that particular setup:

> - Every new task creates a new queue on the server, with thousands of
>     tasks the broker may be overloaded with queues and this will affect
>     performance in negative ways. If you’re using RabbitMQ then each
>     queue will be a separate Erlang process, so if you’re planning to
>     keep many results simultaneously you may have to increase the Erlang
>     process limit, and the maximum number of file descriptors your OS
>     allows
> - Old results will not be cleaned automatically, so you must make
>     sure to consume the results or else the number of queues will
>     eventually go out of control. If you’re running RabbitMQ 2.1.1 or
>     higher you can take advantage of the x-expires argument to queues,
>     which will expire queues after a certain time limit after they are
>     unused. The queue expiry can be set (in seconds) by the
>     CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES setting (not enabled by default).

From what I've read in the [changelog](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.3-archived/changelog.html#version-2-3-0), this is no longer the default backend in versions >=2.3.0 because users were getting bit in the rear end by this behavior. I'd suggest changing the results backend if this not the functionality you need.

Comment: CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES has been deprecated, CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES is the new config setting name. Default is now to save it for 1 day, setting it to 0 means keep forever.

Answer (score 3):

The CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES dictates the time to live of the temp queues. The default is 1 day. You can modify this value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because [celery workers remote control](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#remote-control) is enabled (it is enabled by default).

You can disable it by setting the [CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-enable-remote-control) setting to False
However, note that you will lose the ability to do things like add_consumer, cancel_consumer etc using the `celery command`

Answer (score 0):

`amqp` backend creates a new queue for each task. If you want to avoid it, you can use `rpc` backend which keeps results in a single queue.

In your config, set

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
```

You can read more about [this on celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend).