# Why are Celery + RabbitMQ creating queues automatically when I've disabled that behavior explicitly?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

First things first: I have `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = False` in my celeryconfig, and I launch a celery worker with `celery worker -Q queue1`. I can see by monitoring that `queue1` is created, and that the worker is listening on it. Now, when I launch a task that is routed (via `CELERY_ROUTES`) to `queue2`, I can see that `queue2` is created; can someone explain this behavior? Note: I think that what I'm asking is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144025/temporary-queue-made-in-celery), because I see, understand, and can control the lifetime of the temporary queues created to store the results. What I want to know is why auxiliary queues are being created.

Comment: Please provide the queue names in question

Comment: I did: "queue1", "queue2" were the names I gave in my explanation. The actual names are slightly different, though, but without an explanation of the significance of the names (e.g., there are not weird characters like punctuation in them), the ones I gave should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

When the worker boots, Celery automatically creates queues that are explicitly specified with the `-Q` argument and/or the `CELERY_QUEUES` setting.

The `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES` setting refers to other queues that aren't specified using either of those two mechanisms when the worker boots.  For example, if you specify an unlisted queue to one of your task decorators.

```
@app.task(queue='some-new-queue'):
def some_task(params):
    pass
```

When Celery figures out that `some-new-queue` doesn't exist, it will create it for you, but only when the `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES` setting is True.  Otherwise it will error out.