# Unknown queue names show on Rabbitmq mgmt. when using Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I only created the last 2 queue names that show in Rabbitmq management Webui in the below table:

[image]

The rest of the table has hash-like queues, which I don't know:

> ```
> 1- Who created them? (I know it is celery, but which process, task,etc.)
>
> 2- Why they are created, and what they are created for?.
> ```

I can notice that when the number of pushed messages increase, the number of those hash-like messages increase.

Comment: `.pidbox` queues are used to control the workers by broadcasting commands to them: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#workers   Then the `celeryev` queues are used by monitors and other tools that want to subscribe to events.  There are two types of events: worker and task.  The workers will consume worker related events to synchronize logical clocks. Flower is a web based monitor that also subscribes to task related events: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor

Comment: As the answer below said, the hash named queues are task results when you use the amqp result backend.  This backend does not perform very well, and it's better to use a database if you want to store results on disk, or if you want RPC calls you should use the new rpc backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using celery, Rabbitmq is used as a default result backend, and also to store errors of failing 
tasks(that raised exceptions).

Every new task creates a new queue on the server, with thousands of tasks the 
broker may be overloaded with queues and this will affect performance 
in negative ways.

Each queue in Rabbit will be a separate Erlang process, so if you’re planning to
keep many results simultaneously you may have to increase the Erlang
process limit, and the maximum number of file descriptors your OS
allows.

*Old results will not be cleaned automatically*, so we have to tell 
rabbit to do so.

The below conf. line dictates the time to live of the temp 
queues. The default is 1 day

```
CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = Number of seconds
```

OR, We can change the backend store totally, and not make it in Rabbit.

```
CELERY_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

We may also ignore it:

```
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True.
```

Also, when ignoring the result, we can also keep the errors stored for later usage,
which means one more queue for the failing tasks.

```
CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED = True.
```

I will not mark this question as answered, waiting for a better answer.

**Rererences:**

- This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144025/temporary-queue-made-in-celery) link
- Celery documentation
- Rabbitmq documentation

Comment: Note that there is also a new RPC backend in Celery 3.1 that creates one queue per client

Comment: @asksol, Thanks for your comment. Who is calling this RPC? And what queue is created per client?

Comment: There are two AMQP based result backends: 1) the 'amqp' result backend which stores results on disk and using one queue per task so that the result can be retrieved by any process and 2) the 'rpc' result backend (new in Celery 3.1) which uses one queue per client to send results (not on disk) and only the process that initiated the task can retrieve the result.    You have to explicitly enable these result backends, as by default celery does not do anything with the return values.

Comment: Did you get any more clarity on this?  I'm using a db backend to store results and I still see the pidbox queues.  My understanding is that the ev queues are for monitoring with a tool like flower like you pointed out.

Comment: same question here (and not using a result backend)... @asksol can you confirm if pidbox queues are _only_ used for remote control of workers as described here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/workers.html#remote-control or have other uses?