# How to Delete temporary RabbitMQ queues once corresponding result has been retrieved?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

My question builds off this one: [Temporary queue made in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144025/temporary-queue-made-in-celery)

My application needs to retrieve results, as it uploads them to an S3 file. however, the number of temporary queues being made is causing my broker to crash (machine doesn't have enough memory). I want to delete the temporary queue once the corresponding result as been retrieved. In my celery client script, I am iterating through a list of of results (where each result is from function.delay() ):

```
for result in result_list:
    while True:
        if result.ready():
            #do something with result
            #I WANT TO DELETE TEMPORARY QUEUE HERE
```

Is there any way I can achieve the above -- deleting the temporary queue once the result has been retrieved?

I would have used CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES option in my celeryconfig , but I don't know when I can safely clean up the temporary queue, as the result may not have been retrieved. Is there anyway I can delete specific queues in this script (note that I have the queue Id from the result).

ADDITIONAL NOTE:

I am running all rabbitmq servers in a cluster with HA enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this was to use the rabbitmqadmin from rabbitmq. I downloaded it via

```
wget localhost:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin
```

after installing the management plugin

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Make sure your user has the administrator tag for rabbitmq, or you will not be able to perform commands. I then deleted the queue in my script using python subprocess import and rabbitmqadmin delete queue name='' . Keep in mind that the queue name is the same as the corresponding result id, except without the hyphens.

Also make sure you add the params -v myvhost -u myusername -p mypassword in rabbitmqadmin commands, default vhost is /.

I believe this will delete queues across all nodes in a cluster, though I am not completely sure of this.